# Smooch.js overrides (window | global).Promise

Tags: angular, ionic2, smooch

When integrating Smooches web interface in an Angular 2 application, I receive this error.

```
es6.promise.js:117 Unhandled promise rejection Error: Zone.js has detected that ZoneAwarePromise `(window|global).Promise` has been overwritten.(…)
```

My Script tags in my index.html look like this:

```
<script src="https://cdn.smooch.io/smooch.min.js"></script>
<script>
    Smooch.init({appToken: 'an4tq3kng5aw0xknv6wvhedlg'});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved in this [blog post](https://thielcole.github.io/ionic2/2016/11/15/smoochjs-ionic2-integration.html).

Generally, the issue was the order in which you import javascript files in your index.html file.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Zone.js takes control of the global Promise object. You might want to try loading Smooch using requirejs, browserify, or webpack to see if it helps.

Comment: Ionic 2 RC uses Rollup, so I will have to look at loading it via these scripts. I have looked through and it seems to be an conflict in which Zone.js cannot use anyone elses es6-promise library. More research to be done, but I solved it temporarily by includeding the script as the last script I import.